# Noindex BuddyPress members directory subpages

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

The BuddyPress members directory is broken into a number of subpages e.g.

```
example.com/members/?upage=2
example.com/members/?upage=3
```

How can I set the subpages to 'noindex' so they are not indexed by search engines such as Google? Note, I would like the main members directory page ( example.com/members ) to be indexed.

I have tried Yoast's SEO plugin which allows you to noindex WordPress archive subpages (such as tags and categories) but this doesn't work for the BuddyPress members directory.

https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo

Answer (score 0):

Suggest adding a robots.txt file similar to this:

```
Disallow: */activity/p/*
Disallow: /docs/
Disallow: *send-invites*
Disallow: */groups/*members*
Disallow: */groups/*media*
Disallow: *widget-title*
Disallow: *members/*activity*
Disallow: *members/*notifications*
Disallow: *members/*friends*
Disallow: *members/*groups*
Disallow: *members/*docs*
Disallow: *members/*media*
Disallow: *acpage*
Disallow: *messages*
Disallow: *friends*
Disallow: *settings*
Disallow: /*/comment-page*
Disallow: *register*
Disallow: *login*
Disallow: *profile*
Disallow: *admin*
Disallow: *includes*
Disallow: *content*
```

to prevent some other quirky indexing issues with bp.
Note that it doesn’t guarantee Googlebot et al won’t index these pages, it just requests that they don’t.